# Key error when generating boost interface in Py++

Tags: python, c++, arrays, boost, key

I am using Py++ and CastXML to parse a C++ header file and produce a boost.python interface using the python script below:

```
# Configurations for compiler and generator
generator_path = "/usr/bin/castxml"
generator_name = "castxml"
compiler = "gnu"
compiler_path = "/usr/bin/gcc"



# Create configuration for CastXML
xml_generator_config = parser.xml_generator_configuration_t(
    xml_generator_path=generator_path,
    xml_generator=generator_name,
    compiler=compiler,
    compiler_path=compiler_path,
    include_paths = [misc include files]
    )

# List of all the C++ header of our library
header_collection = [
    "/path/to/header/header.h"]
    
# Parses the source files and creates a module_builder object
builder = module_builder.module_builder_t(
    header_collection,
    xml_generator_path=generator_path,
    xml_generator_config=xml_generator_config)

# Automatically detect properties and associated getters/setters
builder.classes().add_properties(exclude_accessors=True)

# Define a name for the module
builder.build_code_creator(module_name="pymodule")

# Writes the C++ interface file
builder.write_module('pymodule_pylib.cpp')
```

I run this script and input my header but it consistently comes up with this error:

```
KeyError: '(('/usr/include/c++/7/tuple', 343), ('::', 'std', '_Inherited'))'
```

I traced this back to the following function in pygccxml where it seems it is trying to build the declaration hierarchy and it does not find the above key in the array noted below:

```
def _join_class_hierarchy(self, namespaces):
        classes = [
            decl for decl in pygccxml.declarations.make_flatten(namespaces)
            if isinstance(decl, pygccxml.declarations.class_t)]
        leaved_classes = {}
        # selecting classes to leave
        for class_ in classes:
            key = self._create_key(class_)
            if key not in leaved_classes:
                leaved_classes[key] = class_
        # replacing base and derived classes with those that should be leave
        # also this loop will add missing derived classes to the base
        for class_ in classes:
            leaved_class = leaved_classes[self._create_key(class_)]
            for base_info in class_.bases:
                leaved_base = leaved_classes[
                    self._create_key(base_info.related_class)]
                # treating base class hierarchy of leaved_class
                leaved_base_info = pygccxml.declarations.hierarchy_info_t(
                    related_class=leaved_base, access=base_info.access)
                if leaved_base_info not in leaved_class.bases:
                    leaved_class.bases.append(leaved_base_info)
                else:
                    index = leaved_class.bases.index(leaved_base_info)
                    leaved_class.bases[
                        index].related_class = leaved_base_info.related_class
                # treating derived class hierarchy of leaved_base
                leaved_derived_for_base_info = \
                    pygccxml.declarations.hierarchy_info_t(
                        related_class=leaved_class,
                        access=base_info.access)
                if leaved_derived_for_base_info not in leaved_base.derived:
                    leaved_base.derived.append(leaved_derived_for_base_info)
                else:
                    index = leaved_base.derived.index(
                        leaved_derived_for_base_info)
                    leaved_base.derived[index].related_class = \
                        leaved_derived_for_base_info.related_class
            for derived_info in class_.derived:

                #---------Line where code fails----------

                leaved_derived = leaved_classes[
                    self._create_key(
                        derived_info.related_class)]
                # treating derived class hierarchy of leaved_class
                leaved_derived_info = pygccxml.declarations.hierarchy_info_t(
                    related_class=leaved_derived, access=derived_info.access)
                if leaved_derived_info not in leaved_class.derived:
                    leaved_class.derived.append(leaved_derived_info)
                # treating base class hierarchy of leaved_derived
                leaved_base_for_derived_info = \
                    pygccxml.declarations.hierarchy_info_t(
                        related_class=leaved_class,
                        access=derived_info.access)
                if leaved_base_for_derived_info not in leaved_derived.bases:
                    leaved_derived.bases.append(leaved_base_for_derived_info)
        # this loops remove instance we from parent.declarations
        for class_ in classes:
            key = self._create_key(class_)
            if id(leaved_classes[key]) == id(class_):
                continue
            else:
                if class_.parent:
                    declarations = class_.parent.declarations
                else:
                    # yes, we are talking about global class that doesn't
                    # belong to any namespace. Usually is compiler generated
                    # top level classes
                    declarations = namespaces
                declarations_ids = [id(decl) for decl in declarations]
                del declarations[declarations_ids.index(id(class_))]
        return leaved_classes
```

I have not been able to overcome this error and am not sure what could be causing it. I did print out the other keys that are used to search the `leaved_derived` array and its interesting because there is this one: `(('/usr/include/c++/7/tuple', 185), ('::', 'std', '_Inherited'))` which is very similar (line number in first tuple is 185 not 343) but produces no error. Any explanation as to what could possibly be going on here would be greatly appreciated